# Декодировать ссылку на изображение на python data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG.... (парсинг)

Tags: requests, bs4, base64

Всем добрый день, нигде не нашел как декодировать ссылку на изображение при парсинге сайта на python.
Вернее декодровать получается, но по факту выходит:

b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\t\x08\x04\x00\x00\x00\x91#d\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x10IDATx\xdacd \x00\x18G\x15\x80\x01\x00\x06\xf6\x00\n\xaa\xfe\xbe\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

вместо адреса ссылки. Пробовал и ascii и utf-8 и другие ...

---

```
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import base64


def base_decode(message):
    cards = base64.b64decode(message)
    return cards


URL = "https://renault.ru"
headers = {
    "accept": "image/avif,image/webp,*/*",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 
    Firefox/97.0"
    }

req = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
home = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(home, "lxml")
card = soup.find("div", class_="RangeModelsPicker__modelsList").find("div", 
    class_="RangeModelCard").find("button", 
    class_="RangeModelCard__imageLink").find("picture", 
    class_="LazyPictureElement").find("img",                                                                                                  
    class_="PictureElement__imgDefault")["src"]

pic = card.split("base64,")[1]
decoded_card = base_decode(pic)

print(decoded_card)
```

Comment: Это сама картинка в бинарном виде, а не ссылка. так что декодированное содержимое в файл пишите в двоичном режиме и вот вам готовая картинка

Comment: with open('arkana.png', 'wb') as file:
#     file.write(decoded_card)

Comment: попробовал таким образом, получил пустую картинку с белым квадратиком)) видимо что-то делаю не так....((

Comment: А может это и есть картинка с белым квадратиком. в виде такого встроенного кода обычно в страницу включают мелкие элементы оформления, а не что то важное. потому что важное обычно большое по размеру и в страницу его так включать не выгодно. скорее всего вы берете из страницы не то что нужно